# Firebase rules/secure in collectionGroup use if state

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a problem with firebase rules.

At this moment i try to set new rules for more security in my db.

My problem is that in my flutter code I'm using a collectionGroup
and I don't know how I can specify the rules.

In firebase rules I have created this code:

- doc -> product_id (contains random number and user_id)
- path -> path to product_details

```
//check product details
match /{path=**}/product_details/{doc}{
      
//check the user own the product -> is it -> he has all rules
allow read : if(doc.split('_')[2] == request.auth.uid);
      
//check the user own the product -> is not -> only can only read
allow write : if(doc.split('_')[2] != request.auth.uid);
      
//coming soon -> admin rules -> write/delete/read/update
}
```

To check the user is in his own product i split the product_id.
The product_id contains also the user_id.

My plan is the user can only read, write, update and delete his own product.

Products from other user can only read.

Its just a example.

If I set the in the code above the state 'allow read' my app works fine.

But I'm changing the state (for example with a if state) i got an error in my app.

In firebase debug my code works fine.

In flutter the collectionGroup looks like this code:

```
//collection group all collection with 'product_images'
    Query<Map<String, dynamic>>  collectionGroupImage = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collectionGroup('product_images');

//get data from collection group
var query_product_images = await collectionGroupImage.get();
```

The error i got in my app looks like this code:
[image]

My Database:
Path: /user/user_id/data/product_data/product_details/product_id/paramter(price,discription...)

[image]

I add all product from one user into the user (see path above)

My problem is, if i want show all products in my app
i need all products id's.
To solve this problem i make a collectionGroup on my 'product_details'.
Now i can get all values in my products.
Until now its work.

If any questions feel free to ask me.

Anyone have a idea how i can set a if state in code.
Many thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want a user to be able to see all product_details data: Use this rule for your collection group

```
match /{path=**}/product_details/{docId}{
  allow read: if true;
  // allow read: if (request.auth != null); use this line if you want to 
  // allow only logged in users.
}
```

Then, to prevent a user from modifying another users data, use something like this

```
function isLoggedIn() {
  return request.auth != null;
}
function isOwner(detailsId) {
  return isLoggedIn() && detailsId.split('_')[2] == request.auth.uid;
}
match /product_details/{detailsId} {
  allow update, delete, create: if isOwner(detailsId);
}
```

Comment: Hello Peter, 
thx for your answer.
I need the collectionGroup to show all product from all useres.
In your example (i think) i only select my products.
Tahts not waht i want to do.
In my question i updated my db to exmplain better my problem.

Comment: If you want your collectionGroup to show products from all users, then your firestore rules should be: match /{path=**}/product_details/{docId}{allow read: if true;} or if you want only logged in users to read all products data, your firestore rules should be: match /{path=**}/product_details/{docId}{allow read: if (request.auth != null);}

Comment: Hello Peter, thx for your answer. This is working. But how can I check the user owns the product? For that i need the userId. But i dont know how i can get it from 'path=**'?
Thats why im split the product number. The product number contains the id_randomNumber_UserID. But if im split its not working. In debug mode firebase its working?
Have you a idea? Many thx

Comment: Check out my updated answer. Notice how I passed detailsId inorder to get userId. Try that. It should work. If it doesn't let me know if its create or update that fails.

Comment: Its working fine. Many Thx (:. You save my Day

Comment: Glad I could help.